# Call same method on multiple objects

Tags: c#

I have a number of methods that are called on different 3rd party systems. I now have another 3rd party system that will have the same set of methods actioned against it. If both 3rd party systems are connected I will then call the methods on each object in turn.

Currently I have a class that I pass round that I can call the method once and it checks and then calls it on each system that is enabled, this has an instance of each objects classes, similar to this:

```
 public class AACSCaller 
    {

        3rdPartySystem1 _system1;
        3rdPartySystem2 _system2;

        public AACSCaller(Settings appSettings)
        {
            _appSettings = appSettings;
            if (appSettings.system1Enabled)
            {
                _system1 = new 3rdPartySystem1();
            }
            if (appSettings.system2Enabled)
            {
                _system2 = new 3rdPartySystem2();
            }
        }
        public void Method1()
        {
            if (appSettings.system1Enabled)
            {
                _system1.Method1();

            }
            if (appSettings.system2Enabled)
            {
                _system2.Method1();

            }
        }

        public void Method2()
        {
            if (appSettings.system1Enabled)
            {
                _system1.Method2();

            }
            if (appSettings.system2Enabled)
            {
                _system2.Method2();

            }
        }
    }
```

Is this sensible, as it does seem there maybe a better way and I may well be connecting additional system at some point.

Comment: Are you the author of the classes `3rdPartySystem1` and `3rdPartySystem2`? Why not use interfaces?

Comment: Yes I am. Even if using interfaces would i still need to instantiate each object, so have two objects interfaces, one for each object?

Comment: You would have a collection (e.g. List) of interfaces, e.g. List<IThirdPartySoftware> where you could add each instantiated object even though they're of different types, as long as they implement the same interfaces it will be correct. After that just iterate through the list and call your shared methods.

Comment: Is there any benefit, as will i not still need my helper method to iterate the list of interfaces?

Comment: @David You need just one instance. You can implement this with Dependency injection or just if in the constructor.

Comment: @David you will need to iterate over the list of interfaces in each method like `Metod1` but when you have to change only `AACSCaller` constructor if new external system is added. Also you can push iteration to the helper method, like `void Iterate(Action<IThirdPartySoftware> _) { foreach (var s in _thirdPartyList) _(s); }` and then you can use it like `void Method1() { Iterate(_ => _.Method1); }`

Comment: @David if you have a situation, when both systems are enabled, you'll have to manage a list of them. Have a look at my answer below

Comment: Hi Pavel, I get you. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution here is to define an interface or base class for `3rdPartySystem1` and `3rdPartySystem2` classes, store instances in a collection and call required methods for every item in collection. If only one system is enabled, you'll have only one item in collection, if both is enabled, you'll call them one by one in loop

```cs
public interface IThirdPartySystem
{
    void Method1();
    void Method2();
}

public class ThirdPartySystem1 : IThirdPartySystem
{
    //implementation
}

public class ThirdPartySystem2 : IThirdPartySystem
{
    //implementation
}

public class AACSCaller 
{
    IList<IThirdPartySystem> _systems = new List<IThirdPartySystem>();

    public AACSCaller(Settings appSettings)
    {
        _appSettings = appSettings;
        if (appSettings.system1Enabled)
        {
            _systems.Add(new ThirdPartySystem1());
        }
        if (appSettings.system2Enabled)
        {
            _systems.Add(new ThirdPartySystem2());
        }
    }
    public void Method1()
    {
        foreach (var system in _systems)
            system.Method1();           
    }

    public void Method2()
    {
         foreach (var system in _systems)
            system.Method2();            
    }
}
```

Comment: This code will work but is a bad practice to hold two members instead of one from the interface type.

Comment: Why are you need a List if you have only one element in the List?

Comment: There is no mention in OP, that systems can't be enabled together. _If both 3rd party systems are connected I will then call the methods on each object in turn._ this is a point

Comment: One issue is if I have a return value on one of the methods say if Method1 returns an integer as it adds a value to a database.

Comment: @David you can update interface declaration, set return type to `int` for `Method1`, implement in all classes

Comment: But if you are calling method1 twice (on both interfaces) you will have two different int returned so may need to return a list of ints or something?

Comment: Yes, of course, for `AACSCaller` you should aggregate values somehow and return a collection or single number, it depends on your logic

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use interface that have `Method1` and `Method2` methods and then create to classes `System1` and `System2` that are implements the interface. Where AACSCaller is create you initialize the correct implementation of the interface and in your methods your just Call to the correct instance method without conditions.

```
public class AACSCaller 
{
    IThirdPartySystem ThirdPartySystem;

    public AACSCaller(Settings appSettings)
    {
        _appSettings = appSettings;
        ThirdPartySystem = appSettings.system1Enabled ? new ThirdPartySystem1() : new ThirdPartySystem2();

    }

    public void Method1() => ThirdPartySystem.Method1();

    public void Method2() => ThirdPartySystem.Method2();
}

public interface IThirdPartySystem
{
    void Method1();
    void Method2();
}

public class ThirdPartySystem1 : IThirdPartySystem
{
    public void Method1()
    {
        //code here..
    }

    public void Method2()
    {
        //code here..
    }
}

public class ThirdPartySystem2 : IThirdPartySystem
    {
        public void Method1()
        {
            //code here..
        }

        public void Method2()
        {
            //code here..
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think i understand but could you give a simple example please (as I'm a bit of a simpleton)?

Comment: I give you an example, enjoy (:

Comment: Thanks but will this works if I have both systems connected at the same time. Also there maybe a 3rd system at some point in the future?

Comment: No, you can change to ICollection<IThirdPartySystem> and it will work.